# bootstrap panel and pseudo class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pseudo-element

I have this [bootstrap and custom css](http://www.bootply.com/7h2JKXv40U#) that generates nice "books on shelves". When I use the code itself it works. But when I insert the code in the div:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">....code from the link...</div>
```

suddenly the shelves disappear. I noticed that somehow pseudo elements (:before, :after) stop working when I use them in panels. Do you have an idea what is going on? Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

bootstraps panel has a background color of white that overrides your `:before` and `:after` css.

```
.panel {
   background-color: #fff; /*GET RID OF THIS*/
}
```

(you can choose to do this in different ways:

1. you can change the native bootstrap (not recommended, and you cant if you're using cdn).
2. add a different class on the panel and put this code in:

   `.newClass { background-color: none !important; }`

(you can use `none` or `transparent`) either one will get your shelves css back

Comment: Thank you. I actually did that, but then I loose the white background of the panel that i needed. when I add the white background to class="panel-body" then again I loose the shelves.